# Are write-skew anomalies are possible in Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Based on what the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#isolation_and_consistency) says about transaction isolation in Google Cloud Datastore, [write-skew anomalies (ssi-vldb12.pdf#2.1.1)](https://drkp.net/papers/ssi-vldb12.pdf) must be possible. Am I right?

Comment: In the documentation it is stated for [transaction operation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions) that "a transaction cannot concurrently modify the data that is read or modified by another transaction". Can you rephrase your question? Are you asking if write skew example is prevented in Datastore?

Comment: yes, I am asking exactly whether the write-skew behaviors of the txs are possible. Like in the example showed in wikipedia: "In a write skew anomaly, two transactions (T1 and T2) concurrently read an overlapping data set (e.g. values V1 and V2), concurrently make disjoint updates (e.g. T1 updates V1, T2 updates V2), and finally concurrently commit, neither having seen the update performed by the other." That's the simplest case of such anomaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written few tests to demonstrate write-skew and read-skew anomalies in datastore transaction isolation ([sitano/datastore-writeskew](https://github.com/sitano/datastore-writeskew)). These tests failed to demonstrate expected behavior. Datastore transaction manager detects conflicting reads and writes and aborts (restarts) transactions that may cause these anomalies at least in represented cases.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Datastore enforces serializable isolation [[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/transactions#isolation_and_consistency)]. Which means each transaction executed serially, without overlapping in time [[2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation)],[[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability)].

According to the wikipedia article, [Snapshot isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation):

> In a write skew anomaly, two transactions (T1 and T2) concurrently
>   read an overlapping data set (e.g. values V1 and V2), concurrently
>   make disjoint updates (e.g. T1 updates V1, T2 updates V2), and finally
>   concurrently commit, neither having seen the update performed by the
>   other. **Were the system serializable, such an anomaly would be
>   impossible**, as either T1 or T2 would have to occur "first", and be
>   visible to the other. In contrast, snapshot isolation permits write
>   skew anomalies.

Comment: > Cloud Datastore enforces serializable isolation...
It is not. The doc is only stating internal serializability for the transactions which means that from inside of the transaction, transaction is observing serializable behavior like it is only one which is currently processing, but externally it is not the case. Externally the doc states exactly read committed like semantics for the transactions, and under read committed isolation it's impossible to prevent write-skew anomalies in an easy way. RC isolation only promises you absence of dirty reads and dirty writes. That doesn't prevent WS.

Comment: > Which means each transaction executed serially, without overlapping in time...
That's not the case either. Internal serializability is only an illusion for the tx alone. Globally or externally transactions uses optimistic concurrency control to implement read committed isolation which means that they do overlap. It's only forbidden for them to read-write the same keys what is detected with the last update/access time version check.

Comment: Could you post your conclusions as an answer and autoaccept it so if more people has the same question they can see it? Thanks!

Comment: @Iñigo yes, I'll do, but want to write code prove first.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan Prisyazhnyy (OP) pointed out, Datastore [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation) is Serializable  *inside transactions* but *outside transactions* it's Read Committed, which only prevents Dirty Reads, no write-skew anomalies.

Here are some examples of how it works [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation#examples).